# Accessing innermost child div not working using eval not working

Tags: puppeteer

Hi I have this div format and I'm trying to access div with parent class b and child with classname of g

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        <div class="c">
            <div class="e">
                <div class="f">
                </div
                <div class="g">
                </div
            </div
        </div
    </div
    <div class="x">
        <div class="c">
            <div class="e">
                <div class="f">
                </div
                <div class="g">
                </div
            </div
        </div
    </div
</div
```

And below is my sample code

```
  await page.waitForSelector('.b');
  const divElements = await page.$('.b');

  const innerDivClass = divElements .$eval('.g', div => div.className);
```

And I'm getting error failed to find element matching selector ".g" even though I there is div with classname of g

Answer (score 0):

The html part seems to be wrong; you are not closing the div tags `</div` should be `</div>`. Then your code works as is, it gets just the first `g` class even if you replace class `b` with `a` *(you can see if you replace `div.className` with `div.textContent` in the example below)*.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const html = `
    <div class="a">
        <div class="b">
            <div class="c">
                <div class="e">
                    <div class="f"></div>
                    <div class="g">test1</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="x">
            <div class="c">
                <div class="e">
                    <div class="f"></div>
                    <div class="g">test2</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
`;


let browser;
(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    await page.setContent(html);

    await page.waitForSelector('.b');
    const divElements = await page.$('.b');

    const innerDivClass = await divElements.$eval('.g', div => div.className);

    console.log(innerDivClass);
    await browser.close();

})().catch(err => console.error(err));
```

if you want to get values of both divs with class g then you need to replace

```js
await page.waitForSelector('.b');
const divElements = await page.$('.b');

const innerDivClass = await divElements.$eval('.g', div => div.className);
```

with just

```js
const innerDivClass = await page.$$eval('.g', el => el.map(x => {return {class: x.className, text:x.textContent}}));
```

or *(note instead of `.e` you could also use `.c` or `.a > div`)*

```js
let divs = await page.$$('.e');

let innerDivClass = [];
for (let d of divs) {
    let dClass = await d.$eval('.g', el => el.className);
    let dText  = await d.$eval('.g', el => el.textContent);
    innerDivClass.push({class : dClass, text : dText});
}
```

if you just want the class names then

```js
const innerDivClass = await page.$$eval('.g', el => el.map(x => x.className));
```

if you just want to get values from under class b *(for x replace the `.b` with `.x`)*

```js
const innerDivClass = await page.$$eval('.b .g', el => el.map(x => {return {class: x.className, text:x.textContent}}));
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to add that there is another div container that has g. Kindly Update your Answer